# Ubuntu 20.04 - Static and default routes via netplan

Tags: networking, 20.04, netplan

I am brand new to Linux. I only started 'playing' yesterday, so please forgive my lack of knowledge.
I have built a linux server with 2 network cards. Outside interface (ens192) for all Internet traffic and an INSIDE interface (ens160) for all internal traffic. All interfaces are STATIC.
I would like a single default route to be on the OUTSIDE (ens192)
I would like to route all other networks INSIDE (ens160)

Please see below what I have attempted to build so far.

```
network:
version: 2
renderer: networkd
ethernets:
  ens160:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [172.24.0.50/23]
      gateway4: 172.24.0.5
      routes:
      - to: 10.0.0.0/8
        via: 172.24.0.5
      - to: 172.23.0.0/19
        via: 172.24.0.5
      - to: 172.17.10.0/24
        via: 172.24.0.5
```

I am currently receiving this error - /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml:15:1: Invalid YAML: tabs are not allowed for indent:
- to: 172.17.10.0/24

I have received this error with a previous configuration.

** (generate:5240): WARNING **: 10:16:53.463: Problem encountered while validating default route consistency.Please set up multiple routing tables and use `routing-policy` instead.
Error: Conflicting default route declarations for IPv4 (table: main, metric: default), first declared in ens192 but also in ens160

I am at a complete loss on what to do here.

Please help.

Comment: Welcome, please edit your post and add the current configuration of  ens192.

Comment: Do you have a tab between : and 172 by any chance? The error suggests there is a tab where there shouldn’t be one. Try using spaces to indent by 2.

Answer (score 0):

There is most likely an error in your yaml-code, probably a tab instead of a space at the last route.

If you edit the file in vim you can use the `:set list` -command to see what characters that hides there. To get back use the `:set nolist` -command.

Comment: Thank you. Thats great. I will give that a go.

Do you know how I can remove the 2 default routes?